# Page length bug in IE9 on Windows 7

Tags: css, windows-7, internet-explorer-9, whitespace

I've a got a weird issue where users in Native IE9 and Windows 7 have additional white space / page length / or whatever it should be called, rendering below the sticky footer. It happens intermittently although still often.

I have made several changes in an attempt to fix;

- Changed the Sticky Footer CSS a few times
- I've removed the Facebook feed from the sidebar temporarily (which showed a reduction in the frequency, but not 100%)
- Verified page is not rendering in Quirks mode
- Verified it doesn't happen in any modern browser (IE10+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari)
- Verified that I cannot recreate in IE9 mode in IE10

Basically I am at a loss to identify let alone explain what bug could be causing this to occur - and thus I have no way to fix it.

To illustrate the problem I have [attached a screenshot](https://skycitycareers.co.nz/test/bug_ie9_extra_vert_space.jpg)!. Note the vertical scroll bar also.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky without some code to go from, but I'll hazard a guess that you have the following style in place:

```
html {
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```